# Running pylint with pylint_django throws error

Tags: django, pylint

Installed pylint with pip.
Installed pylint-django with pip.
When pylint is invoked with `pylint --load-plugins pylint_django /projectsource`
throws the following erros

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "../bin/pylint", line 11, in
>   
>       sys.exit(run_pylint())   File "../lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/**init**.py", line 16, in
>   run_pylint
>       Run(sys.argv[1:])   File "../lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 1268, in
>   **init**
>       linter.load_plugin_modules(self._plugins)   File "../lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 495, in
>   load_plugin_modules
>       module.register(self)   File "../lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint_django/plugin.py", line 22, in
>   register
>       start = name_checker.config.const_rgx.pattern[:-2] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pattern'

Please help!

Comment: When pylint is invoked with --load_plugins option, it is going into pylint-django module and failes while running the register script.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the Pylint 1.8.1
Error is gone when it is downgraded to 1.7.5.
[Here is the link to bug report](https://github.com/landscapeio/pylint-django/issues/108)